# How to sum a column value in a list of hashmaps against different Keys in java

Tags: java, loops

I have a List of HashMaps that are

```
1. Key/value             key/Value
   CODE=1                TOTAL=10

2. Key/value             key/Value
   CODE=1                TOTAL=10

3. Key/value             key/Value
   CODE=2                TOTAL=10

4. Key/value             key/Value
   CODE=2                TOTAL=10

5. Key/value             key/Value
   CODE=3                TOTAL=10
```

I want to get SUM total of the TOTAL columns using CODE as key in java for loop etc

i.e.

iterate over the list
     for each key, show sum (added together) total

console output should be

```
key with CODE 1 has total of 20 as sum
key with CODE 2 has total of 20 as sum
key with CODE 3 has total of 10 as sum
```

I have tried by using

```
int total = 0;
String previousCodeValue = "";
for(int i = 0; i < mapsList ; i++)
{
  Map map = mapsList.get(i);

  if(map.get("CODE") != previousCodeValue && !previousCodeValue.equals("") )
  {
     system.out.print(total);
     total = 0;
  }
    previousCodeValue = map.get("CODE") ;
    total = total + map.get("TOTAL") 
 }
```

The issue is the loops runs fine as long as CODE remains changing, but on the last code value, the logic will not work :( what to do ?

Regards,

Aiden

Comment: Is it possible to change the code so it doesn't use a List of Maps? It would be better design and easier to model this complex data structure using your own classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Iterator` like this:

```
    int totale = 0;
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry tot = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    totale +=  tot.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears all you are missing is outputing the last total after the loop is done :

```
int total = 0;
String previousCodeValue = "";
for(int i = 0; i < mapsList ; i++)
{
  Map map = mapsList.get(i);

  if(map.get("CODE") != previousCodeValue && !previousCodeValue.equals("") )
  {
     System.out.print(total);
     total = 0;
  }
    previousCodeValue = map.get("CODE") ;
    total = total + map.get("TOTAL") 
 }
 System.out.print(total);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will give it a try then will mark it as answer

Comment: This solution assumes the maps are ordered. Do you want to depend on that?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I actually ordered the maps before doing it otherwise it would have been difficult to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you need the SUM of the TOTAL values for each unique KEY over all the maps. Supposedly you would want to do this in one iteration so you need to keep track of unique keys and totals as you go along. Below I keep track of the results in a map (yes, another map, it's just an example).

```
private static void main(String[] args) {
    printResults(determineResults(createMaps()));
}

private static List<Map<String, Integer>> createMaps() {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    maps.add(createMap(1, 10));
    maps.add(createMap(1, 10));
    maps.add(createMap(2, 10));
    maps.add(createMap(2, 10));
    maps.add(createMap(3, 10));
    return maps;
} 

private static Map<String, Integer> createMap(int code, int total) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("CODE", code);
    map.put("TOTAL", total);
    return map;
}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> determineResults(List<Map<String, Integer>> maps) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map<String, Integer) map : maps) {
        Integer key = map.get("CODE");
        Integer sum = results.get(key);
        if (sum == null) {
            sum = 0;
        }
        Integer total = map.get("TOTAL");
        sum += total;
        results.put(key, sum);
    }
    return results;
}

private static void printResults(Map<Integer, Integer> results) {
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> result : results) {
        System.out.printf("key with CODE %s has total of %s as sum", result .getKey(), result.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What a clean solution, simply amazing :) I took me some time to debug and understand the  logic you used. Will try to put this into my code and give it a try.